# Scrape a MediaWiki website (specific html tags) using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I would like to scrape this specific MediaWiki website with specific tags. Here is my current code.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Strfind"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

If you look at the URL, there is the `description`, `parameters`, `return values` and the `example usage`. That's what I would like to scrape. Thank you!

Comment: The first requested elements have classes. So you can get them by soup-methods and not from text. And what have you tried to get the result from text? There are several approaches you can do: parsing html, extract text with regular expressions, ...

Comment: no need to kill all script it will not executed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way to do this but the following uses css selectors to grab that information

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as re

url ="https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Strfind"
response = re.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

description = soup.select_one('.description').text
initial_parameters = soup.select('.parameters,.param')
final_parameters = [parameter.text for parameter in initial_parameters]
returnValues = soup.select_one('#bodyContent > .param + p + div').text
exampleUsage = soup.select_one('.pawn').text

results = [description,final_parameters,returnValues,exampleUsage]
print(results)
```